# Delete video and calculate statistic from youtube user account when not logged on youtube

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

I want to use the youtube api on my website. It will be possible to a user to upload a video from our website to **his** youtube account.(Via youtube api)

Is there anybody know if it's possible to delete the video from the youtube user's account from our application if the user is not currently using our website ? Like a year after he uploaded the video.

I also want to be able to track statistic on the same video. Ex : Played count ... Shall I use the Youtube Video ID to be able to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. You have to upload the video on your account and the user account.

When you upload the video on your account you specify that you are the owner of the content. More information about how to do it : https://cms.youtube.com/cyc/YouTube_Content_Feed_Specification_Asset_Policies.html

It's also possible to track statistic of those videos with the Content Management System of Youtube: http://www.youtube.com/t/content_management